# Rotating a rectangular solid about the y axis without image distortion using canvas renderer (three.js)

Tags: html, canvas, three.js

I've spent several hours trying to work around this issue... when rendering  really simple shape (ie. a cube with very low complexity) and using a texture map feature of Three.js, when you rotate the cube the image seems to be distorted while in rotation, and then you can see a line which runs across the surface of the cube which appears as distortion.

http://screencast.com/t/VpSPRsr1Jkss

I understand that is a limitation of canvas rendering - but it seems like this is is a really simple thing to do - rotate a cube that has an image on one face without the distortion.

Is there another canvas library or approach i can take?  I was really looking forward to using Three.js for animating some logos and other elemnets - but we can't have distortion like that in a logo or a customer facing landing page.

Thanks for reading, I'm open to suggestions here.

I don't accept increasing the complexity of the face as a solution because that just distributes the distortion through out the face. I really just want to render the image to a flat surface and be able to rotate that object.

Comment: could you post a live example of your source code somewhere so we could look at it?

Comment: It is pretty standard code for using the Mesh based texture mapping. Are you saying you know of a scenario that canvas renderer doesn't create distortiion on image mapping?  The WebGL renderer does this fine, but obviously is available on fewer browsers.

Comment: I'll try to post some more detailed information / examples soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distortion you see is because only two triangles make that plane.
A quick fix is to have more detailed plane.

If you are using PlaneGeometry, increase the number of segments.
If you are using CubeGeometry, increase the number of segments on the plane you need (2 out of 3).

It will take a bit of fiddling to find the best balance between a decent look and optimal performance (as more segments will require more computing). Hopefully for simple scene you'll get away with no major delays.

Comment: Thanks, but this is really not good, because increasing the number of triangles that make the plan simply increase the number of lines of distortion - it doesn't help it just changes the distortion.

If its a matted texture you would never notice, but if its words or a logo, its painfully obvious and unusable for production, polished site.

Also I note in my question that this is not a solution I'm looking for as it doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: @DanielBaughman Tessellating the plane should diminish the effect but not completely fix it. Can you use the CSS3D ? The [Period Table](http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html) example looks pretty good. If not, how about using text as paths (non extruded) with the Canvas renderer on top of a plane (with a bit of distance to avoid z fighting) ?

Comment: That's a nice example.
The big difference I see is that those are not images rendered into the plane it uses words, also I can't really tesselate here because again - i have artwork and logos to display on the sides of the cube.

Yes, I am forced into doing this via CSS3 and then having a downlevel hack for the older browsers.... but damn this was so close and would be so awesome if it worked in Canvas.  There just has to be some way to do this.

Comment: I'm afraid textures on canvas arem't pretty. The other option is to have vector versions of the logos and render them as paths, which would be crisp but cpu intensive I imagine. For complex images this wouldn't be an option.

Comment: Question: while my knowledge of the math and such that goes into creating the texture map is not complete, shouldn'it it be possible to somehow manipulate the way the texture map is applied to the object to use squares or rectangles instead of triangles? Then you would only have one face that side of the cube.

Comment: If there was a way to not have that distortion, believe me, we would have implemented already. That's a limitation of CanvasRenderer. Considering that you're only using planes, as George suggested, I would use CSS3DRenderer instead. With CSS3DRenderer you can use an image as a texture, doesn't need to be only text. Whatever you can put in a <div> will work.

Comment: The CSS3D renderer is awesome and it works, but only IE10 and later is working for me, even on the example.  So that doesn't give the cross browser compatability i need.

Comment: I guess you don't have a lot of choices then. My suggestion is focus on the CSS3D renderer and maybe provide a canvas fallback with a tessellated plane/cube but also display a message like: "for a quality experience please use a modern browser like (insert your CSS3D compabile browsers here)"