# How to resolve distortion resulting from canvas texture applied to non-rectangular ThreeJS quad mesh

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, html5-canvas, texture-mapping

This [CodePen](http://codepen.io/joeycato/pen/ggObPJ) demonstrates the issue I am trying to resolve ( tested with Chrome & Firefox)

Notice that the rendered text and orange block are distorted near the seam. Not sure why this is happening since the triangles forming the quad share the same vertices?

```
var COMPONENT_SCREEN_W = 192,
    COMPONENT_SCREEN_H = 160,
    FINAL_SCREEN_W = 256,
    FINAL_SCREEN_H = 256,
    QUAD = [{
      x: -2,
      y: 228
    }, // TL corner
    {
      x: -22,
      y: -173
    }, // BL corner
    {
      x: 322,
      y: -266
    }, // BR corner
    {
      x: 348,
      y: 220
    }, // TR corner
  ],
  canvas,
  ctx,
  camera, scene, renderer, geometry, texture, mesh;

function makeCanvas(id, w, h) {
  var elem = document.createElement('canvas');
  elem.id = id;
  elem.width = w;
  elem.height = h;
  return Object.assign(elem);
}

function setupCanvas(ctx, smoothingEnabled) {
  ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = smoothingEnabled;
  ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = smoothingEnabled;
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = smoothingEnabled;
  ctx.oImageSmoothingEnabled = smoothingEnabled; /* Opera */
  ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = smoothingEnabled; /* Safari */
}

initDemo();
animateDemo();

function initDemo() {
  var demoWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var demoHeight = window.innerHeight;
  canvas = makeCanvas('canvas', FINAL_SCREEN_W, FINAL_SCREEN_H);
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(demoWidth, demoHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, demoWidth / demoHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.x = 100;
  camera.position.y = 100;
  camera.position.z = 200;
  scene.add(camera);
  texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture
  });

  var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
  geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(QUAD[0].x, QUAD[0].y, 0));
  geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(QUAD[1].x, QUAD[1].y, 0));
  geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(QUAD[2].x, QUAD[2].y, 0));
  geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(QUAD[3].x, QUAD[3].y, 0));
  geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
  geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(2, 3, 0));
  geom.computeFaceNormals();
  geom.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];
  geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push([new THREE.Vector2(0, 1), new THREE.Vector2(0, 0), new THREE.Vector2(1, 0), ]);
  geom.faceVertexUvs[0].push([new THREE.Vector2(1, 0), new THREE.Vector2(1, 1), new THREE.Vector2(0, 1), ]);
  geom.uvsNeedUpdate = true;

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
  mesh.rotation.y = 0.1; // 0.2;
  scene.add(mesh);

  setupCanvas(ctx, true);

  requestAnimationFrame(animateDemo);
}

function animateDemo() {
  drawCanvas(ctx);
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animateDemo);
}

function drawCanvas(ctx) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, COMPONENT_SCREEN_W, COMPONENT_SCREEN_H);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, COMPONENT_SCREEN_W - 20, COMPONENT_SCREEN_H - 20);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
  ctx.fillRect(20, 40, 50, 10);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  ctx.fillRect(60, 40, 50, 10);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillRect(120, 40, 50, 10);

  ctx.font = '16pt Arial';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  for(var j=20; j<=140; j+=20) {
    ctx.fillText('TEXT TEXT TEXT', 4, j);      
  }  
}
```

Thanks,
Joey

Comment: Read about Affine Texture Mapping [here](http://extremelysatisfactorytotalitarianism.com/blog/?p=2120). I think that explains the issue pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the article. Makes sense now. I suppose ThreeJS/WebGL avoid perspective-correct transformations for performance reasons? I suppose I can work around this by using a (rectangular) plane mesh, and fiddle with the camera settings so it approximates the quad shape I'm looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051872/rotating-a-rectangular-solid-about-the-y-axis-without-image-distortion-using-can